# Como usar SQLITE RunInTransactionAsync

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8-1

Eu preciso inserir uma grande quantidade de linhas (exatamente 221) quando eu inicio minha aplicação WP. Na verdade eu estou usando arrays e laço de repetição `for`, assim eu estou perdendo performance quando inicia o app.

Pesquisei um pouco a respeito do `RunInTransactionAsync`, não achei muita coisa mas, existe alguma maneira de deixar esse `insert` mais rápido?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 221; i++)
{
   var hino = new hinos() { numHino = array.numeroHinos[i], favHino = array.favHinos, nomeHino = array.nomeHinos[i], catHino = array.categoriaHinos[i], letraHino = array.letraHinos[i] };
   await con.InsertAsync(hino);                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma das formas é dentre de uma transaction e reutilizar o Smtm(Statement que é compilado) mas isso utilizaria um API mais baixo.

Não sei o *API* que tens disponível mas existe vários passos num *statement* do SQLite:
`sqlite3_prepare()` -- compila a query
`sqlite3_step()` -- reproduz
`sqlite3_finalize()` -- termina

A minha sugestão é utilizar o mesmo valor do `sqlite3_prepare()`

Answer (score -1):

Uma sugestão que eu vi [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database) é de fazer essa forma:

```
INSERT INTO 'tablename'
          SELECT 'data1' AS 'column1', 'data2' AS 'column2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'data1', 'data2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'data1', 'data2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'data1', 'data2'
```

Na época eu não implementei, mudei meu conceito, espero que te ajude.